# Improving performance of HTML5 canvas with thousands of rectangles drawn per frame

Tags: javascript, optimization, html5-canvas

I am creating a waterfall graph based on live spectrum data pulled from a server. The canvas is set currently to render 100 rows of time data with 64 points per line (maximum of 64,000 rectangles rendered per frame). Within a web worker, the following snippet controls rendering:

```js
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// ...
// map points to colors using d3.scaleSequential(...)
// (little impact on performance)
// ...

for (let [color, points] of Object.entries(colorCoordinates)) {
  context.fillStyle = color;
  for (let point of points) {
    context.fillRect(...point);
  }
}
```

This is already an upgrade over a previous approach which involved setting colors in a linear fashion (`context.fillStyle` was modified thousands of times; very slow). The approach above performs somewhat adequately, but is sluggish approaching 30fps.

Another approach I tried, based on other questions, was to use `beginPath` + `rect` + `fill`:

```js
for (let [color, points] of Object.entries(colorCoordinates)) {
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.beginPath();
  for (let point of points) {
    context.rect(...point);
  }
  context.fill();
}
```

However, tested in three browsers, this approach was approximately half as slow each time, which surprised me.

Please give me some tips on other techniques I can use to optimize my graph.

Comment: Check out WebGPU API : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/your-first-webgpu-app#8

Comment: Do the rect's move , or only color changes, If the rects do not move (or there is no relative movement between rects of same color) using a Path2D to define and render rects of given color may give a performance boost. Or even pre rendered rectangles on a canvas using compositing to set color will work. But as previous comment pointed out your best option is WebGL or WebGPU and/or WASM

Comment: Is there a chance you can link to your project? It's already the third question you ask about it and it feels there is something off with it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) to avoid the drawing cost on each iteration of your loop.

- [draw 10,000 objects on canvas javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468218/draw-10-000-objects-on-canvas-javascript);
- [rendering huge number of elements in html5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61642773/rendering-huge-number-of-elements-in-html5-canvas).

2. You can avoid `text-rendering`, or put it in another layering canvas on top of it;
3. Avoid floating-point coordinates and use integers instead, to avoid sub-pixel rendering cost.